# Cover-Up method on 1 to infinity?

Tags: calculus

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{7}{n(n+3)}$$

I know this is convergent but I do not know how to apply "cover-up method" to solve this can I get some help pls?

The answer I got is $77/18$

Comment: What is the "cover up method"

Comment: Maybe using telescoping concept?

Comment: OP probably means telescoping sum ... I get $ \frac{77}{18}$ too.

Comment: "Cover-up method" is sometimes in reference to partial fraction decomposition.  In this case finding what values of $A$ and $B$ work such that $\frac{7}{n(n+3)}=\frac{A}{n}+\frac{B}{n+3}$.  The phrase comes from the non-rigorous explanation "*To find the value of $A$, go to your original fraction and "cover up" the $n$ (which is the corresponding denominator in the decomposition) and plug in the value which would have made it equal to zero, in this case $n=0$*" In doing so we get $A=\frac{7}{3}$ and $B=\frac{7}{(-3)}$

Answer (score 3):

If by *cover-up method* you mean creative telescoping, well:
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{7}{n(n+3)}=\frac{7}{3}\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+3}\right) = \frac{7}{3}\left(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\right)=\color{red}{\frac{77}{18}}.$$
As an alternative:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{7}{n(n+3)} = 7\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^{n+2}}{n}\,dx = 7\int_{0}^{1}-x^2\log(1-x)\,dx $$
and the last integral equals $ 7\int_{0}^{1}-(1-x)^2\log(x)\,dx$ that is simple to compute by IBP (Integration By Parts).

Comment: why is the limit of the integral 0 to 1? i forgot...

Comment: @Sooo: $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n+2}}{n}\,dx = \frac{1}{n(n+3)}$$ as wanted. The magic does not work if you take a different integration range: essentially, you want to write $\frac{1}{n(n+3)}$ as the integral of $\frac{x^n}{n}\,\omega(x)$ over some fixed interval, for some fixed weight function $\omega(x)$. In our case the interval is $(0,1)$ and the weight function is $x^2$.

Comment: jee thx alot! I got a tone to review